# Parse exponential Value in Xml document

Tags: c#

I have an issue when deserializing an object (which I cannot modify).
I receive an exponential value for certain xml element and for represent them in my class I used decimal value expect that when I deserialize the xml document it fails.

```
<fwdRate>-9.72316862724032E-05</fwdRate>
```

Is there any solution to represent this attribute other than create 2 attributes in my class to represent it (one string and the other a decimal value)?

Can I create a custom deserializtion class for decimal value?

```
        private void ParseXML(string value)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SwapDataSynapseResult));
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(value))
            {
                _result = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as SwapDataSynapseResult;
            }
        }
```

As Demand

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fwdRate")]
    public decimal FwdRate { get; set; }
}       
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         string val = "<result><fwdRate>-9.72316862724032E-05</fwdRate></result>";
         Result response = ParseXML(val);
  }
  static Result ParseXML(string value)
  {
      XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
      using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(value))
      {
         return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Result;
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]? Post it on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ , https://tio.run/#cs-core , https://repl.it/ or else

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com Updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XML, decimal values are not allowed to use scientific (exponential) notation (See [this link](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77057.html) at the 'Restrictions' paragraph).

Either:

- the value is indeed a floating point one: Put a `float`/`double` instead of a `decimal` in the code.
- the XML is corrupted.

In the same way, in C#, by default, [Decimal.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't accept exponential representation.
You can override this behavior by implementing a new struct that wrap a `decimal` and implement `IXmlSerializable` and allow exponential representation when de-serialized:

```
public struct XmlDecimal : IXmlSerializable
{
    public decimal Value { get; private set; }

    public XmlDecimal(decimal value) => Value = value;

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var s = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        Value = decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowExponent,
            NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out var value)
            ? value
            : 0; // If parse fail the resulting value is 0. Maybe we can throw an exception here.
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) => writer.WriteValue(Value);

    public static implicit operator decimal(XmlDecimal v) => v.Value;

    public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();
}
```

The flaw is that you have to use this struct instead of a `decimal` everywhere in your model.

And sadly you can't make this struct read-only, has explained [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/03/02/implementing-ixmlserializable-in-readonly-structs/).

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is to control how your properties are deserialized by implementing the IXmlSerializable interface:

[IXmlSerializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=netframework-4.8)

[IXmlSerializable code project example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly)

In the ReadXml method you should convert your number

```
var yourStringNumber = ...

this.fwdRate = Decimal.Parse(yourStringNumber, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

But this method will require you to parse of the whole xml manually that is a bit overhead sometimes.

A simple solution (that smells but might be useful) is just to add additional  fwdRateDecimal field to your class and fulfill the value after the serialization.

```
 private void ParseXML(string value)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SwapDataSynapseResult));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(value))
        {
            _result = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as SwapDataSynapseResult;
            _result.fwdRateDecimal = Decimal.Parse(_result.fwdRate, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float)
        }
    }
```

**Also conversion can be implemented in a type directly:**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fwdRate")]
    public string FwdRateStr { get; set; }

    private string lastParsedValue = null;
    private decimal fwdRate = 0;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public decimal FwdRate 
    { 
     get 
     {
        if(FwdRateStr != lastParsedValue)
        {
             lastParsedValue = FwdRateStr
             fwdRate = Decimal.Parse(FwdRateStr ,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float)
        }

        return fwdRate
     }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I will go with option 1 by using IXmlSerializable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fwdRate")]
    public double FwdRate { get; set; }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string val = "<result><fwdRate>-9.72316862724032E-05</fwdRate></result>";
        Result response = ParseXML(val);
        Console.WriteLine(response.FwdRate);
    }
    static Result ParseXML(string value)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(value))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Result;
        }
    }

}
```

You can't modify the incoming xml but you can modify how you read its' data.

Read that number as a `double` instead of `decimal` and you will have the right decimal precision.

Output:

> -9,72316862724032E-05

Comment: By reading it as `double` you may introduce rounding errors. Try `1.1e-1`. Decimal are here to avoid that. `decimal.TryParse` can accept the `NumberStyles.AllowExponent` flag.